# Lisp simple question

Tags: lisp, printing, clisp, let

I have some not understanding actions from gnu clisp
Suppose, I have some code like  `(let ((x "Hi!"))(print x))`. 
If I execute it from console (like, clisp fileName.lisp) I see

> Hi!

But, when I execute it from interpreter, I see this text twice. Why?

Help me, please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The interpreter always outputs the value of the last expression.
`print` also returns the parameter as a value, `"Hi!"` in your case.
That's why you see it twice.

```
(print "Hi!")
```

will give the same result.